# Nginx as reverse proxy for Minio server: force serving index.html for bucket directories

Tags: nginx, minio

I have self hosted Minio server with a bucket that I want to serve from a different domain, thus have configured a Nginx reverse proxy with the following config:

```
worker_processes auto;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
} 

http {
    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        proxy_intercept_errors on;

        location / {
            if ($request_uri = "/") {
                return 200 "Static file server is running\n";
            }
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_pass http://minio-server;
        }
    }    
    upstream minio-server {
        server minio.data.svc.cluster.local:9000;
    }
}
```

This nginx instance is deployed on a Kubernetes cluster, so I have an ingress with let´s say `static.example.com`, pointing to the nginx container.

The proxy is working fine If I access a specific file directly, but I want to use this bucket as static site hosting, so when accessing a directory, it should render the respective `index.html` file inside that directory.

I think I have to use rewrite rules, but I have tried a couple and could not get any to work. Or it gave me redirection loops or didn't work at all.

Any help would be appreciated